# Outlook VBA Access Folders in Shared Mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I have some VBA code in Outlook which behaves perfectly for the main Mailbox - however the same code is struggling when I add a secondary mailbox - this is Outlook 2016.

It seems to be struggling with reading the sub folders - I can get it to read mail items in the Inbox, but not the sub folders.

Code :

```
Dim sharedemail As Outlook.Recipient
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myDestFolder Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim strSubject As String
Dim i As Integer

Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sharedemail = myNameSpace.CreateRecipient("recip@domain.com")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedemail, olFolderInbox)  

For itemCount = myInbox.items.Count To 1 Step -1 'Iterates from the end backwards

    Set item = myInbox.items(itemCount)
    strSubject = UCase(item.Subject)

    Select Case True

        Case InStr(strSubject, UCase("Holiday Request")) > 0
        'Set destination folder
        Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("HolidayRequests")
        'move the email out of inbox
        item.Move myDestFolder

    End Select

Next
```

It stalls at the Set myDestFolder line as it can't seem to select that sub folder - as I say same code seems to work fine in main Inbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Outlook keeps shared default folders in the primary OST file, and it does not sync the subfolders.

You can either

1. Uncheck the "Download shared folders" checkbox
2. Use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) - that would be fairly complex as you'd need to retrieve the autodiscover XML for that mailbox and construct the store entry id appropriately.
3. use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - its version of [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetSharedDefaultFolder` returns an online version of the folder ([RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm)) with all its subfolders.